# How to simulate unchecking a checkbox and clicking a button using javascript in a website?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have for example the following site:

https://dailyuploads.net/eoeunkj2at5d

When opened it views a checkbox and a button. I have to uncheck the checkbox then I can click the download button.

My question is how can I simulate unchecking the checkbox and clicking the download button using javascript by entering the javascript commands directly in the browser (i.e. by writing the keyword "javascript" followed by ":" and the javascript commands)?

Thank you

Comment: And where exactly would you be typing `javascript:command` to execute it on an external page?

Comment: I mean to write it in the url address field located above most internet browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This line below makes you able to uncheck the `checkbox`.

```
document.getElementById("chkIsAdd").checked = false;
```

If you use this like @Robert Parham said you toggle the uncheck/check function.

```
document.getElementById("chkIsAdd").click();
```

And this line trigger the button function.

```
document.getElementById('downloadBtnClick').click();
```

**EDIT**

Add these lines in your javascript file and put this `GET` parameter in your URL.

> ....php?uncheck=true

```
function executeByUrl() {
  document.getElementById("chkIsAdd").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("chkIsAdd").click();
}

(function() {
 if (window.location.search.indexOf('unchek=true') > -1) {
   executeByUrl();
 } else {
   alert('nope');
 }
})();
```

If you want to execute javascript in the URL thats not possible. Firstly the browser wouldnt support javascript from URL second the `DOM` is not ready accessing the website.

You can open up the console and type or copy paste that code I give you before.

Comment: I don't know but I tested the above lines by writing them directly in the url address field of my Firefox browser on android prefixed by "javascript:" but they have no effect.

Comment: If you want to execute these lines in on your website, give some GET parameters in the URL and check the parameter and call a function which contains these lines.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me some example please?

Comment: Yes, wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("button/input id").click()
```

Should take care of both.